# Not getting popup window after using editGridRow() in JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Below is my code for getting pop up window to add new row in my jqgrid.

```
$("#bedata").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $("#usergrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{width:300,height:420, reloadAfterSubmit:true});
});
```

Whats wrong with this, I am getting alert window but not the popup window.
Yes, My all column have `editable:true` attribute with them.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you posted should work. If it doesn't work than you made some typing error. For example `$("#usergrid")` could be not a grid. You can validate that `$("#usergrid")` is a grid by testing that `$("#usergrid").length === 1`, `typeof $("#list")[0].grid === "object"` and `typeof $("#list")[0].p === "object"`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I tested with alert($("#usergrid").length); and getting 1. You sure that there are no other attribute that we have to set to get the popup window? like viewrecords: true, editrecords: true, rownumbers: true, gridview : true etc.

Comment: @Jaikrat: Is `typeof $("#list")[0].grid === "object"` and `$("#list")[0].p === "object"` too? No attributes are required. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Jaikrat.htm). If you will don't find the error yourself you should post the URL to the demo or prepare the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for creating example for me first. alert($("#usergrid")[0].grid === "object");, alert($("#usergrid")[0].p === "object"); are giving me false and false. Yes, I edited your code and tested in jsfiddle and its working fine there.

Comment: AND MY CODE IS ALSO WORKING THERE :( but not in my local.

Comment: I tried "editGridRow" with my other jQuery application and tehre its working. Do you think jQuery version could be an issue. Because in my both application I am using different version of jQuery.

Comment: @Jaikrat: if `$("#usergrid")[0].grid !== "object"` then `$("#usergrid")` is not jqGrid. Either you use wrong id (`usergrid`) or you try to execute the code **before** you created jqGrid.

Comment: @Jaikrat: Could you post the URL of jsfiddle demo which have the described problem?

Comment: #Oleg, I am at home now so can not really post the code but yes when I was doing alert on $("#usergrid")[0].grid, I was getting [Object Object]. In my jsfiddle demo, its working where I am using your jquery imports.

Comment: #Oleg, I STRONGLY beleive now that there is something wrong with my jquery files which is stopping popup windows. Becuase I try to implement popup in my other application  and it is working perfectly fine. Do you know which .js file we need to look up for popup functionality?

Comment: In my working app I am using jquery version 1.7.2 and in which its not working there 1.8.3.

Comment: @Jaikrat: **Could you post the URL of jsfiddle demo which have the described problem?** One will see in the demo which versions of jQuery, jQuery UI, jqGrid use use and *how*.

Comment: Atually Oleg, I tried implementing my code there but the imports of jquery was yours i.e. googleapis.com/../.etc. . I took it from your sample code that you had created for me. In my local I have jqeury folder in my application and importing from there. I do not know how to test with different version of jquery import in jsfiddle. just FYI, I tried reomving my imports of jquery1.8.3 and imported jquery1.7.2 and its started working. Any idea, which import is must to get popup window. This is the url of jsfiddle with my code but your imports http://jsfiddle.net/4rpDS/2/. Thanks